# showing a black transparent box over picturebox with an Image

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, windows-style-flags

I have this custom control :

```
public class DrawingArea : Panel
    {
        public DrawingArea()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override this method in subclasses for drawing purposes.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void OnDraw(Graphics graphics)
        {

        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2122:DoNotIndirectlyExposeMethodsWithLinkDemands")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2123:OverrideLinkDemandsShouldBeIdenticalToBase")]
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

                return cp;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            // Don't paint background
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the private member so we can use it in the OnDraw method
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

            // Set the best settings possible (quality-wise)
            graphics.TextRenderingHint =
                System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            graphics.InterpolationMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.SmoothingMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            // Calls the OnDraw subclass method
            OnDraw(graphics);
        }
    }
```

which I inherit from it here :

```
public class SelectScreen : DrawingArea
{
    public SelectScreen()
    {
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
        BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

and on Action :

```
void Action()
        {
            CaptureScreen();
            selectScreen.Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            selectScreen.BringToFront();
        }
```

basically what am trying to do is, capture the screen , then add a black transparent screen over it , so I can use it to crop the picture later.

Comment: In the SelectScreen class, you override OnPaint again, call base.OnPaint first and then draw the border using the graphics object. This will add a border over the captured screen.

Comment: As you are subclassing Panel you can use it BackgroundImage property to display the captured Bitmap. (It supports zooming btw..) And you can simply draw the cropping frame onto its surface in a Paint event..